# What's the convention for describing the location of a quote on a page, without line numbers?

Tags: citations

Assume that: 1. the original text lacks line numbers

2. and  counting the line numbers (for each citation) is too inefficient, for both you and the reader.

Is it conventional to write the beneath?

> This quotation is from p. 10 ( [one of:] Top, Middle, Bottom).

Comment: I think line number is probably more useful than top, middle, bottom.

Comment: @ff524 I emended my post.

Comment: The page has lines, no? You count them to get the line number.

Comment: p. 10, fifth paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

It is not common practice to mention the exact location of a cited item within an article. Citing the item itself would enough most of the times, and citing the page number should suffice.

If you are still concerned about citing the specific page, in the case where the content in the book is dense and heterogeneous, then you may cite them in the way @ff524 or @DanPeterson has suggested.

> p. *n*, *m*th paragraph 
>   p. *n*, *k*th line

where *n* is the page number, *m* is the paragraph number, *k* is the line number.

Comment: Also, one could add a section/subsection number if applicable.